# Change format of hg log -v

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

When we do `hg log -v` we see:

```
changeset:   2639:283fb2da345f
parent:      2638:e06cb712d37b
parent:      2631:d8f619046812
user:        joe@pub.com
date:        Wed Apr 13 12:29:57 2011 -0400
files:       core/src/main/java/com/blah/boards/InvalidRateException.java core/src/main/java/com/blah/boards/InvalidException.java core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AssignInstruction.java core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AutoAssignInstruction.java core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AutoDeliveryInstruction.java 
description:
Commiting after merge
```

Is there a way to output the file in a more readable manner?  Something like:

```
files:       
core/src/main/java/com/blah/boards/InvalidRateException.java 
core/src/main/java/com/blah/boards/InvalidException.java 
core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AssignInstruction.java 
core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AutoAssignInstruction.java 
core/src/main/java/com/blah/area/xxx/instructions/AutoDeliveryInstruction.java
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your own template via `--template` option. See `hg help templates`. You could try e.g.

```
hg log --template "(...) files:\n{files|stringify|fill76}\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the files list for a single revision you can use `hg status --change 2639` which shows the file list prefixed with M, A, R, D prefixed, which you can omit by adding the `--no-status` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but anyway, here goes a solution:

```
hg log -v  --template "{files % '{file}\n'}"
```

Worth checking this: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#template-usage